# Re-opening a question which appears to be inappropriately closed

Tags: discussion, voting, closed-questions, vote-to-close, specific-question

Here is a question which has been closed based on being "off topic":  [What would reality be like without causality?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/93395/what-would-reality-be-like-without-causality)

I at least consider this question to be entirely central to philosophy.  I don't know how to imagine a universe without causality of some kind, even if the causes are "random".  The centrality of causation to universe conceptions is therefore a significant observation of the limitations of our mental toolkit and/or actual limitations to how a universe may work.

I consider sorting between the two (is this intrinsic to the world, or to our conceptions), is as central a philosophic question as one can come up with.

This question garnered over 2000 views, 8 answers, and 11 upvotes on one of those answers -- so our community also found it of great relevance.

I believe that advocacy here for a reopen vote is one of the roles for Meta PhS, so  am posting such a request.

Comment: I had nothing to do with the close vote, but I do think the question hangs in the liminal space of "it's not quite developed enough to have a concise enough answer for this platform".  I think the format of this site is such that a sort of "comment triaging" might potentially revise and update the question to try to extract a useful answer or two from it.

Comment: 11 upvotes for one answer is -- far better than the "useful" feedback for my average answers. If a question generates 8 answers, to my mind it is on target for this site.